# How to get image from MySQL from WindowsForms

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to INSERT a bitmap image (jpeg, png, jpg) from WinForms PictureBox to MYSQL DB BLOB attribute and read it out to that pictureBox again.
Insert executes OK:

```
user.Img = pictureBoxFoto.Image;

sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO`gclinic`.`user`(`Img`)VALUES (@img);";
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@img", user.Img));

if (sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
{
 throw new InvalidProgramException("Erro: SQLuser - add() Throw() - mysql ");
}
```

THE PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE ON READ FROM MYSQL:

```
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Img")))
    {
        Byte[] byteBLOBData = new Byte[0];
        byteBLOBData = (Byte[])(reader["Img"]);
        MemoryStream stmBLOBData = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);
        user.Img = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData);
    }
```

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll "Parameter not valid" exception loading System.Drawing.Image

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code.

```
byteBLOBData[0]=new Byte();
```

Comment: Sorry but i´m newcomer. Where to?